# Trying to stop CSS animation at full

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Goal: finished product as picture attached with only the bubbles rising inside the glass.[image: Finished product with bubbles rising]

**Hey, I am working on this CSS /JS code and I need the final version of filled glass only with bubbles and foam on top (ignoring all the delays and fillings in animations). I tried but somehow unsuccessful, any suggestions where to edit the code? thanks**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pour') 
    .delay(2000)
    .animate({
      height: '360px'
      }, 1500)
    .delay(1600)
    .slideUp(500);
  
  $('#liquid') 
    .delay(3400)
    .animate({
      height: '170px'
    }, 2500);
  
  $('.beer-foam') 
    .delay(3400)
    .animate({
      bottom: '200px'
      }, 2500);
  });
```

```css
body { background-color: #0065bd }

h2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: whiteSmoke;
}

#container {
  height: 370px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  width: 248px;
}

#container div { position: absolute; }

.pour {
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: #0065bd;
  border-radius: 10px
}

#beaker {
  border: 10px solid #FFF;
  border-top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 14px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

#beaker:before,
#beaker:after {
  border: 00px solid #FFF;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
  content: '';
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  width: 30px;
}

#beaker:before { left: -50px; }
#beaker:after { right: -50px; }

#liquid {
  background-color: #0065bd;
  border: 10px solid #0065bd;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 180px;
}

#liquid:after {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  bottom: -10px;
  content: '';
  height: 200px;
  left: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
  width: 110px;
}

#liquid .bubble {
  -webkit-animation-name: bubble;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bubble {
  0% { bottom: 0; }

   50% {
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
      bottom: 80px;
   }

   100% {
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
      bottom: 160px;
   }
}

.bubble1 {
  left: 10px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1000ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
}

.bubble2 {
  left: 50px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 700ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1100ms;
}

.bubble3 {
  left: 100px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1200ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1300ms;
}

.bubble4 {
  left: 130px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1100ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 700ms;
}

.bubble5 {
  left: 170px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1300ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 800ms;
}

/* Foam */

.beer-foam {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.foam-1, .foam-2, .foam-3, .foam-4, 
.foam-5, .foam-6, .foam-7 {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}
.foam-1 {
  top: -30px;
  left: -10px;
}
.foam-2 {
  top: -35px;
  left: 20px; 
}
.foam-3 {
  top: -25px;
  left: 50px; 
}
.foam-4 {
  top: -35px;
  left: 80px; 
}
.foam-5 {
  top: -30px;
  left: 110px; 
}
.foam-6 {
  top: -20px;
  left: 140px; 
}
.foam-7 {
  top: -30px;
  left: 160px;
}

/* Drunk Text */

@-moz-keyframes drunk {
    0% { 
    -moz-transform: rotate(0); 
    -moz-transform-origin: top left; 
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
  }
  
    20%, 60% { 
    -moz-transform: rotate(80deg); 
    -moz-transform-origin: top left; 
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
  } 
  
    40% { 
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg); 
    -moz-transform-origin: top left; 
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
  }
  
    80% {
      -moz-transform: rotate(60deg) translateY(0); opacity: 1; 
    -moz-transform-origin: top left; 
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
  }
  
    100% { 
    -moz-transform: translateY(700px); 
    opacity: 0; 
  }
}

@keyframes drunk {
    0% { 
    transform: rotate(0); 
    transform-origin: top left; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
  }
  
    20%, 60% { 
    transform: rotate(80deg); 
    transform-origin: top left; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
  }
  
    40% { 
    transform: rotate(60deg); 
    transform-origin: top left; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
  }
  
    80% { 
    transform: rotate(60deg) translateY(0); 
    opacity: 1; transform-origin: top left; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
  } 
    100% { 
    transform: translateY(700px); 
    opacity: 0; 
  }
}

.drunk {
    -webkit-animation-name: drunk;
    -moz-animation-name: drunk;
    animation-name: drunk;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="pour"></div>
  <div id="beaker">
    <div class="beer-foam">
      <div class="foam-1"></div>
      <div class="foam-2"></div>
      <div class="foam-3"></div>
      <div class="foam-4"></div>
      <div class="foam-5"></div>
      <div class="foam-6"></div>
      <div class="foam-7"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="liquid">
      
      <div class="bubble bubble1"></div>
      <div class="bubble bubble2"></div>
      <div class="bubble bubble3"></div>
      <div class="bubble bubble4"></div>
      <div class="bubble bubble5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<h2 class="animated drunk">Please Wait! While you are entered in Game</h2>
```

Comment: inspect your code at the end of the animation to understand what CSS is applied and replicate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Filling the glass instantly, but bubbles moving

To instantly fill the glass, you can remove the delay:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        /*Look here*/

        $('.pour')
            .css({
                height: '360px'
            })
            .delay(0)
            .slideUp(500);

        $('#liquid')
            .css({
                height: '170px'
            });

        $('.beer-foam')
            .css({
                bottom: '200px'
            });
       
    });
```

```css
body { background-color: #0065bd }
    
    h2 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 400px;
        font-size: 36px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
        color: whiteSmoke;
    }
    
    #container {
        height: 370px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        top: -20px;
        width: 248px;
    }
    
    #container div { position: absolute; }
    
    .pour {
        position: absolute;
        left: 45%;
        width: 20px;
        height: 0px;
        background-color: #0065bd;
        border-radius: 10px
    }
    
    #beaker {
        border: 10px solid #FFF;
        border-top: 0;
        border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
        height: 200px;
        left: 14px;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 200px;
    }
    
    #beaker:before,
    #beaker:after {
        border: 00px solid #FFF;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
        content: '';
        height: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -40px;
        width: 30px;
    }
    
    #beaker:before { left: -50px; }
    #beaker:after { right: -50px; }
    
    #liquid {
        background-color: #0065bd;
        border: 10px solid #0065bd;
        border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 180px;
    }
    
    #liquid:after {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
        bottom: -10px;
        content: '';
        height: 200px;
        left: -40px;
        position: absolute;
        transform: rotate(30deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
        width: 110px;
    }
    
    #liquid .bubble {
        -webkit-animation-name: bubble;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes bubble {
        0% { bottom: 0; }
        
        50% {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
            bottom: 80px;
        }
        
        100% {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            bottom: 160px;
        }
    }
    
    .bubble1 {
        left: 10px;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1000ms;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    }
    
    .bubble2 {
        left: 50px;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 700ms;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1100ms;
    }
    
    .bubble3 {
        left: 100px;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1200ms;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1300ms;
    }
    
    .bubble4 {
        left: 130px;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1100ms;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 700ms;
    }
    
    .bubble5 {
        left: 170px;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1300ms;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 800ms;
    }
    
    /* Foam */
    
    .beer-foam {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .foam-1, .foam-2, .foam-3, .foam-4,
    .foam-5, .foam-6, .foam-7 {
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        background-color: #fefefe;
    }
    .foam-1 {
        top: -30px;
        left: -10px;
    }
    .foam-2 {
        top: -35px;
        left: 20px;
    }
    .foam-3 {
        top: -25px;
        left: 50px;
    }
    .foam-4 {
        top: -35px;
        left: 80px;
    }
    .foam-5 {
        top: -30px;
        left: 110px;
    }
    .foam-6 {
        top: -20px;
        left: 140px;
    }
    .foam-7 {
        top: -30px;
        left: 160px;
    }
    
    /* Drunk Text */
    
    @-moz-keyframes drunk {
        0% {
            -moz-transform: rotate(0);
            -moz-transform-origin: top left;
            -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        
        20%, 60% {
            -moz-transform: rotate(80deg);
            -moz-transform-origin: top left;
            -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        
        40% {
            -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
            -moz-transform-origin: top left;
            -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        
        80% {
            -moz-transform: rotate(60deg) translateY(0); opacity: 1;
            -moz-transform-origin: top left;
            -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        
        100% {
            -moz-transform: translateY(700px);
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes drunk {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(0);
            transform-origin: top left;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        
        20%, 60% {
            transform: rotate(80deg);
            transform-origin: top left;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        
        40% {
            transform: rotate(60deg);
            transform-origin: top left;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        
        80% {
            transform: rotate(60deg) translateY(0);
            opacity: 1; transform-origin: top left;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        100% {
            tran
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="pour"></div>
    <div id="beaker">
        <div class="beer-foam">
            <div class="foam-1"></div>
            <div class="foam-2"></div>
            <div class="foam-3"></div>
            <div class="foam-4"></div>
            <div class="foam-5"></div>
            <div class="foam-6"></div>
            <div class="foam-7"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="liquid">
            
            <div class="bubble bubble1"></div>
            <div class="bubble bubble2"></div>
            <div class="bubble bubble3"></div>
            <div class="bubble bubble4"></div>
            <div class="bubble bubble5"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h2 class="animated drunk">Please Wait! While you are entered in Game</h2>
```

## Pausing the bubbles

To pause the bubbles, you can use the `animation-play-state: paused;` property. This particular way would pause your bubbles after 5.7 seconds:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        /*Look here*/

        setTimeout( () => {
            $('.bubble').css("animation-play-state", "paused");
        }, 5700)

        $('.pour')
            .delay(2000)
            .animate({
                height: '360px'
            }, 1500)
            .delay(1600)
            .slideUp(500);

        $('#liquid')
            .delay(3400)
            .animate({
                height: '170px'
            }, 2500);

        $('.beer-foam')
            .delay(3400)
            .animate({
                bottom: '200px'
            }, 2500);
       
    });
```

```css
body { background-color: #0065bd }
    
    h2 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 400px;
        font-size: 36px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
        color: whiteSmoke;
    }
    
    #container {
        height: 370px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        top: -20px;
        width: 248px;
    }
    
    #container div { position: absolute; }
    
    .pour {
        position: absolute;
        left: 45%;
        width: 20px;
        height: 0px;
        background-color: #0065bd;
        border-radius: 10px
    }
    
    #beaker {
        border: 10px solid #FFF;
        border-top: 0;
        border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
        height: 200px;
        left: 14px;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 200px;
    }
    
    #beaker:before,
    #beaker:after {
        border: 00px solid #FFF;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
        content: '';
        height: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -40px;
        width: 30px;
    }
    
    #beaker:before { left: -50px; }
    #beaker:after { right: -50px; }
    
    #liquid {
        background-color: #0065bd;
        border: 10px solid #0065bd;
        border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 180px;
    }
    
    #liquid:after {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
        bottom: -10px;
        content: '';
        height: 200px;
        left: -40px;
        position: absolute;
        transform: rotate(30deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
        width: 110px;
    }
    
    #liquid .bubble {
        -webkit-animation-name: bubble;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes bubble {
        0% { bottom: 0; }
        
        50% {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
            bottom: 80px;
        }
        
        100% {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            bottom: 160px;
        }
    }
    
    .bubble1 {
        left: 10px;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1000ms;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    }
    
    .bubble2 {
        left: 50px;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 700ms;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1100ms;
    }
    
    .bubble3 {
        left: 100px;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1200ms;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1300ms;
    }
    
    .bubble4 {
        left: 130px;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1100ms;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 700ms;
    }
    
    .bubble5 {
        left: 170px;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1300ms;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 800ms;
    }
    
    /* Foam */
    
    .beer-foam {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .foam-1, .foam-2, .foam-3, .foam-4,
    .foam-5, .foam-6, .foam-7 {
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        background-color: #fefefe;
    }
    .foam-1 {
        top: -30px;
        left: -10px;
    }
    .foam-2 {
        top: -35px;
        left: 20px;
    }
    .foam-3 {
        top: -25px;
        left: 50px;
    }
    .foam-4 {
        top: -35px;
        left: 80px;
    }
    .foam-5 {
        top: -30px;
        left: 110px;
    }
    .foam-6 {
        top: -20px;
        left: 140px;
    }
    .foam-7 {
        top: -30px;
        left: 160px;
    }
    
    /* Drunk Text */
    
    @-moz-keyframes drunk {
        0% {
            -moz-transform: rotate(0);
            -moz-transform-origin: top left;
            -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        
        20%, 60% {
            -moz-transform: rotate(80deg);
            -moz-transform-origin: top left;
            -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        
        40% {
            -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
            -moz-transform-origin: top left;
            -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        
        80% {
            -moz-transform: rotate(60deg) translateY(0); opacity: 1;
            -moz-transform-origin: top left;
            -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        
        100% {
            -moz-transform: translateY(700px);
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes drunk {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(0);
            transform-origin: top left;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        
        20%, 60% {
            transform: rotate(80deg);
            transform-origin: top left;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        
        40% {
            transform: rotate(60deg);
            transform-origin: top left;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        
        80% {
            transform: rotate(60deg) translateY(0);
            opacity: 1; transform-origin: top left;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
        100% {
            tran
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="pour"></div>
    <div id="beaker">
        <div class="beer-foam">
            <div class="foam-1"></div>
            <div class="foam-2"></div>
            <div class="foam-3"></div>
            <div class="foam-4"></div>
            <div class="foam-5"></div>
            <div class="foam-6"></div>
            <div class="foam-7"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="liquid">
            
            <div class="bubble bubble1"></div>
            <div class="bubble bubble2"></div>
            <div class="bubble bubble3"></div>
            <div class="bubble bubble4"></div>
            <div class="bubble bubble5"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h2 class="animated drunk">Please Wait! While you are entered in Game</h2>
```

If you setthe timeout to `5700`, you'll end up with something like this, which is pretty close to your image.

[image: Sto]

## Stopping the bubbles (previous solution)

You could also fiddle with the iteration count and visibility of your bubbles, to kill them after some time, maybe like so:

```
 #liquid .bubble {
        visibility: hidden;  /*Look here*/
        -webkit-animation-name: bubble;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3;   /*Look here*/
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes bubble {
        0% { visibility: visible;  /*Look here*/
             bottom: 0; }
        
        50% {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
            bottom: 80px;
        }
        
        100% {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            bottom: 160px;
        }
    }
```

The numbers depend on the exact effect you'll want, but this would be the way I'd do it. This particular set would send some bubbles and then end the bubbling.

Comment: can you please check the edited version of question, perhaps I was not clear earlier.

Comment: @KamranShakeel Paused the bubbles for you, hope I understood it correctly this time haha

Comment: hahah. actually i need to display "only the glass (already filled on screen and small bubbles rising in it) as my picture attached above, hope this clears more.

Comment: @KamranShakeel Okay, let's see, that'd be one instantly filled glass with bubbles moving or bubbles paused? Cause we can do that too :D

Comment: yes, you are partially right, we would have an ALREADY filled glass (displayed instantly as the code is executed  with rising bubbles :)

Comment: @KamranShakeel okay, let's see: the first heading in my answer gives you an already filled glass with rising bubbles :D If you want to pause the bubbles, add the timeout, now, or keep the bubbles rising... is there anything else I missed? At least this is good practivce, if nothing else :D